# r- flextable runs in script and RMarkdown Chunk but Knitr fails

Tags: r, tidyverse, flextable

Preface: I have found a [similar thread on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48224291/8421707) and ran the steps denoted and it has not fixed the issue, so do not mark as duplicate (also have tried `install.packages("gdtools")`).

I'm using RMarkdown to templatize a Word document that requires a nicer looking table than what you can do within regular Markdown and am trying to use `flextable` [package](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/overview.html#flextable-rendering) to do so so.

I can run a sample within an R Script, and get the following:

```
library(flextable)
ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))
ft <- autofit(ft)
ft
```

[image: flextable runs in r script]

I can run an R code chunk in RMarkdown in RStudio, and get this:

```
library(flextable)
ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))
ft <- autofit(ft)
ft
```

[image: flextable in RMarkdown code chunk]

When I try to `knit`, I get the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'flextable' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
>    unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so':
>     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libcairo.2.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so
>     Reason: image not found
>   Execution halted

How do I get this to Knit into my Word Document?

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages("gdtools")`?

Comment: yes that as well, has not helped (and i just edited question to denote that as well).

Comment: I have tried to knit to HTML and Word. Your code works fine for both on my computer. I wonder if upgrading packages  or R could help.

Comment: I think there are issues with installing Cairo on OSX. I don't use OSX so I'm not up to date with the best way to do it, see questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952427/include-cairo-r-on-a-mac